# Saving frames in a directshow filter

Tags: c++, image, save, directshow

I have an application that relies on a C++ DirectShow transform filter, for the purpose of analyzing what is going on step by step I want to save each frame from the camera that the filter processes. What would be the simplest method to achieve this in the filter itself?

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert [sample grabber filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into the graph?

Beware though: the frame will be in some pixel format, and if it's not RGB24 you'll be in a lot of trouble to analyze it.  If possible, configure your input source to RGB24 and you'll be on your way.

Expand your question if you need more info.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea thanks. I was originally thinking along the lines of manually encoding and writing the frames to disk in the middle of the current filter.